# What is the right algorithm to match regex on a stream?

Tags: algorithms, javascript, regular-expressions, stream-processing

I'd like to match a regex pattern on a stream, but I am not sure what algorithm to use. I certainly don't want to load the entire file into memory.

I tried to figure out how to do this, but I have only very basic ideas. For example I could concat the chunks into some sort of aggregate string as long as I find a match. After that I cut the aggregate at the end of the match and continue. But if there is no match I would end up loading the entire string into memory.

I could give a maximum size to the aggregate, but I might lose matches that way. Another issue that if there is a longer match starting in the same position, then I would miss that. So I guess this algorithm is incompatible with possessive quantifiers too.

Is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: If you want to apply arbitrary regexps to strings which are so huge they fill up all the available memory, I am pretty sure you will run into trouble with any available Javascript regexp engine. Or do you want to implement your own engine?

Comment: The typical way to do this is to know the longest possible match (a URL is probably less than 10K in length for example) And read the data by chunks into a circular buffer of at least double the max match length and after each load try to match the buffer.  This works as long as the thing you are trying to match has a way to find the start and the end so that you know you are matching a complete item - in the case of JSON it is a starting `:"` and ending `[^\\]"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hard problem. Regular expression engines come on twp flavors: NFA and DFA.

1. DFA (deterministic finite-state automata) run efficiently and in limited space, but they cannot do the sort of thing you presumably want, such as capturing and backreferencing substrings of the input. **If** you only need to know *whether* the input matches, not *where*, they're the way to go.
2. NFA (nondeterministic finite automata) fundamentally rely on being able to *backtrack*, i.e. to try something else with input that they have already consumed. And the problem is not limited to possessive quantifiers, but to most constructs: even `(A|B)` requires backtracking.

If there is any way you can limit the possible length of your matches, then it is almost certainly your best option to apply a normal match on overlapping chunks of size `2 * L` than to change the way your regex engine works.

If you do have to change it, though, it would involve analyzing the regex or monitoring the progress of the engine to prove when previous input can no longer be part of *any* match, i.e. when the top-level backtracking has exhausted its alternatives. At that point you can discard characters and so limit the amount of memory required for the entire operation. But be aware that that would be a *fascinating* project, i.e. almost certainly outside the budget if you're just trying to get some random work task done.

Comment: Actually, that is wrong. A pure Regex can be implemented without need for backtracking using either a Finite State Automata, or a Pushdown Finite State Automata. [Take a look here at a good write-up by Russ Cox](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/?_&).

Comment: @Kain0_0 Sure they can, but typically you then lose the interesting functionality that you *actually* want while programming, such as capturing and backreferencing. I assume that OP wants to capture information, not just Booleans.

Comment: @KilianFoth Thanks! For my current case 14GB memory is not enough. I have a massive JSON and I want to extract URLs from it. I have the right constraints to be able to use what I wrote in my question, I was just curious if there is a general solution. According to your answer a non-backtracking regex engine would solve this. It is interesting, because I was looking for a way to solve the redos issue too. I did not realize there are engines without backtracking. https://github.com/uhop/node-re2

Comment: @KilianFoth Warning sour ppl arrived to downvote. :D

Comment: Grep works on streams? @inf3rno

Comment: @KilianFoth: I recommend to rewrite your answer in a way it shows you took non-backtracking implementations into account.

Comment: @KilianFoth URL max length is 2048 characters, so 4096 chars will be good for block size. It can be solved with backtracking engines too, since the pattern is fine from redos prespective, it won't struggle with it. I don't think there is a general solution for this problem, the only way to do it without memory issues is limiting the length. Backtracking is not necessarily an issue this way, it really depends on the pattern.

Comment: @inf3rno 4K blocks won't find something that starts at the end of the block and finishes in the next block - you need a circular buffer.

Comment: @KilianFoth Again incorrect. Push down automata can stow position information in the stack, you can even stow the relevant pieces of information captured from the text and apply relevant transformations. Run these automata in parallel, sharing portions of the stack between instances. These can support look around, back reference, and CF Grammars. Need only provide group level operations such as branch, anchor, cut, join, token, and production-rule, that work on the group of automata branching from the same shared base stack.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I know, I am working on it, but it is not as simple as having a circular buffer That buffer needs to be at least twice the size of the max length to avoid losing matches and when it is that big, then matches can be longer than the max length, so in those cases I'll need to cut the string to make matches shorter or if they don't match by shorter strings, then I'll need to ignore them. But these are just implementation details. I think the most important part is realizing that one needs to set a max length, because there is no solution without constraints.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Backtracking is less important part of the story imho. It is possible to do this with backtracking engines too, but that part of the answer is important for one of my projects where redos is causing a problem.

Answer (score 8):

In general, it is not a good idea to apply a regex to such a huge file at whole. In most real-world cases, files of that size have some kind of structure which can be used to split it into smaller strings in a streaming manner. Applying the regexes only for these "building blocks" will usually result in a way more performant and memory efficient solution.

For example, in a comment, you wrote

> I have a massive JSON and I want to extract URLs from it.

Even without knowing the precise structure of that JSON file, I assume URLs can only occur in string literals. Hence, what you can do here is to

- utilize a JSON streaming library like [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/)
- implement a callback which is called for each string literal where an URL might be contained in the JSON. In that callback, use a regex to detect the URLs within the strings.

But this is just an example, you can probably apply this approach to many comparable use cases.

Comment: I don't know the structure of the json and I don't want to care about that. I guess you missed the " I was just curious if there is a general solution" part...

Comment: You need to know the structure to be able to parse JSON. Or would you just  traverse the whole thing and check every property if it is an URL? For me handling it as plain text is much simpler.

Comment: Another thing that I did not claim I need a solution for JSON files only. If I want to have a specific solution for my problem I write to stackoverflow not here, but I am perfectly capable of solving the problem on my own, I don't need proposed solutions for that. My question was about how to do this in general on plain texts, and I got an answer for that. Yours is just a comment and afaik posting comments as answer here should not be possible, so I'll flag this answer and let others decide about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm jumping the gun by posting here already since my code isn't published as a package yet (it will be `@iter-tools/regex`), but hey I'm bored and I'm working on my OSS projects full time so a `v0.1.0` will be up soon.

I've implemented what I understand to be the (roughly) optimal strategy -- non-backtracking matching with NFAs and captures. In some of the materials here it seems to be referred to as Thompson NFA, though I came to my solution independently starting from simple boolean NFAs. Anyone who is interested can take a look at [the code](https://github.com/iter-tools/regex).